# I need to add a list of Items(Products) to the eBay sandbox user that I've added and display that list

Tags: c#, ebay-net-sdk

I Need To Add a new Item (eBay sandbox) Net SDK, itried from the ebay site and it didn't work (401 error: the URL is wrong). Now I'm trying to use the code from the SDK sample (consoleAddItem)

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,ProdName")] Product product)
        {
            AddItemCall addItemCall = new AddItemCall(apiContext);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                product.Id = addItemCall.Item.ItemID;
                product.ProdName = addItemCall.Item.Title;
                db.Products.Add(product);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(product);
        }
```

Comment: You need to read documentation about EBay Sandbox user account... and use that knowledge to implement whatever you want... If you face any problem in that feel free to ask specific questions here...

Comment: It looks like you wanted to add an image, but did not add the link for it. Would you edit the post either to add the image so it displays, or remove the "[enter image description here]"?